# Recursion Method in JS

Tags: javascript, recursion

first question...be gentle..  I am trying to add zeros in front of a number entered by user, so i'm trying to use recursive method in Vue.  However the return value is always undefined.  Please see my code below.

```
addZeros(num) {
  if (num.length < 7) {
    if (!isNaN(Number(num))) {
      num = '0' + num
      this.addZeros(num)
    } else {
      console.log('error')
      return 'error' //this gets returned no problem
    }
  } else {
    console.log('RETURN:', num) //this shows the correct number but does NOT get returned

    return num  **//why is this not being returned??**
  }

  // return num <-- this will return a value to the caller but basically returns the param coming in
},
```

I'm calling this method from another method,

```
 async rowClicked(item) {
    var my_num = '0'
        my_num = this.addZeros(item)

    //my_num = undefined!!
 }
```

Comment: try `return this.addZeros(num)`

Comment: you need to `return this.addZeroes` in your isNaN if statement.

Comment: That did it!!! thank you so much @danronmoon .... i don't understand why though...

Comment: Recursive functions need an exit condition for all logic paths

Comment: i was just thinking that...thank you @Phil

Comment: I would reach for `String(num).padStart(7, "0")`

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs a return when calling itself. I forget this a lot myself

```js
addZeros(num) {
  if (num.length < 7) {
    if (!isNaN(Number(num))) {
      num = '0' + num
      return this.addZeros(num) // RETURN HERE
    } else {
      console.log('error')
      return 'error'
    }
  } else {
    return num
  }
}
```

You could also look at using [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) to do what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a recursive method then great but this is probably not the best way to implement this function

```js
function addZeros(num) {
  const padding = '0000000';
  const numAsString = num.toString();

  if (numAsString.length === padding.length) {
    return numAsString;
  }

  if (numAsString.length > padding.length) {
    // You could throw an error in here otherwise it will show a number larger than 7 characters
    return numAsString;
  }

  return padding.substr(0, Math.abs(padding.length - numAsString.length))
}
```